# Consequence of violation of independence assumption on estimates of standard errors

Tags: self-study, correlation, sampling, multilevel-analysis, independence

from the first chapter , Introduction to Multilevel Analysis , [p.5 of the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848728468) , it is written that :

> Standard statistical tests lean heavily on the assumption
>   of independence of the observations. If this assumption is violated (and in multilevel data this is almost always the case) the estimates of the standard errors of conventional statistical tests are much too small, and this results in many spuriously ‘significant’ results.

- When units are not independent within a cluster , why are the estimates of the standard errors of conventional statistical tests `much too small` ?

The formula of variance is  $$\mathbb V(X+Y)=\mathbb V(X)+\mathbb V(Y)+2\mathbb {cov}(X,Y)$$

It seems to me from the formula that standard small can smaller or larger if $X$ and $Y$ are independent . Then why is it mentioned that

- the estimates of the standard errors of conventional statistical tests `much too small` ? Only mentioned the word `small` , not `large` .

My 2nd question is :

> Small dependencies in combination with large group sizes still result in large biases in the standard errors .

How can i measure that `even small dependency causes large biases` ? That is , I want to visualize the picture .

Comment: What is the source reference?

Comment: @EricFarng Please see the edit .

Comment: @time, for a good explanation of the clustering problem, also known as the Moulton problem, I recommend you to read chapter 8 of _Mostly Harmless Econometrics_ (an unofficial version can be found [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Joshua_Angrist/publication/51992844_Mostly_harmless_econometrics_an_empiricist%27s_companion/links/00b4953344a9a0cb13000000.pdf), though I would recommend every empirical researcher to buy this excellent book!). In case you are in a hurry, go directly to section  8.2.1 (_Clustering and the Moulton Factor_).